# comparing input parameter with xml value using like in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an SQL table with a column which stores xml like this

```
<AdditionalInfo><RegistrantID>16279</RegistrantID></AdditionalInfo>
```

I have created a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROC hr_GetJobStatusByRegistrantId

@registrantId VARCHAR
AS  
BEGIN  
SELECT TOP 1 
      [IsSubscribed]
  FROM [Hrge].[dbo].[hr_Jobs]
  where AdditionalInfo LIKE  '%<AdditionalInfo><RegistrantID>%' + @registrantId + '%</RegistrantID></AdditionalInfo>%'

  END
```

When I run this stored procedure, I get null:

```
 exec hr_GetJobStatusByRegistrantId '16279'
```

If I make this parameter integer then I get convertion to int error.

Please suggest me solution to this.

Comment: Are you sure the `IsSubscribed` field in the db is not null?

Comment: yes it is not null, if i pass hardcode value like <AdditionalInfo><RegistrantID>16279</RegistrantID></AdditionalInfo>, I get result but when i pass it using string parameter then i guess it becomes like this <AdditionalInfo><RegistrantID>'16279'</RegistrantID></AdditionalInfo>

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the problem is the definition of the parameter. IIRC `VARCHAR` actually means `VARCHAR(1)`. Try putting `varchar(10)` to see if it works

Comment: @SWeko how can i mark you as answer

Comment: Expanded the comment into an actual answer (and added a few more advices that I hope apply :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Just expanding the comment into an answer)

---

You should always specify the width of a char or a varchar field, because unless you do the default kicks in. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) says:

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

which means that in your case you have actually defined `@registrantId` as `VARCHAR(1)` so the value of '16279' was trimmed to a single character ('1') and you actually searched for

```
%<AdditionalInfo><RegistrantID>%1%</RegistrantID></AdditionalInfo>%
```

in the database. This actually returned the IsSubscribed flag for the first record it found in the DB that had a '1' anywhere in the  `RegistrantID` field. You got lucky that the value was something wrong, so you noticed it.

Additionally you are using % around your parameter. This means that when you search for a  `RegistrantID` of 123, you'll get results for 123, 1234, 2123, 51236, etc, etc, and then just take the first one, whichever that one is (decided by the database, since there is no order clause). It's my guess that you need an exact match, so you should remove those, and just use

```
'%<AdditionalInfo><RegistrantID>' + @registrantId
                                           + '</RegistrantID></AdditionalInfo>%'
```

Also, it the `RegistrantId` is actually a number, it would be nice if the interface of the procedure reflected that, so it could be defined with

```
@registrantId int
```

and then converted to a string in the query

```
'%<AdditionalInfo><RegistrantID>' + cast(@registrantId as varchar(10))
                                           + '</RegistrantID></AdditionalInfo>%'
```